# jinja/ansible convert string to boolean

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, jinja2

I need the simple thing - if variable is `false` or empty string, then evaluate to `false`. Otherwise evaluate to true.

I tried `bool(var)` but I'm getting:

```
UndefinedError: 'bool' is undefined
```

Then I tried `var | bool` but even though var is non-empty, that evaluates to `false`. How to make that condition work??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a possible solution in ruby style:

```
    when: not not var
```

But it's rather ugly. Forgot to say that without `not not` the var evaluates to a string so ansible errors out. I hope for a better answer so please add another answer if you have.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that anything other than "true" is going to get evaluated as false when using `var | bool`.

If you are always providing it as a string (eg. `var: ''` or `var: 'false'`) then you can just check for string equality:

```
when: condition == 'false' or condition == ''
```

Optionally adding the boolean check as well if you have that possibility:

```
when: not condition or condition == 'false' or condition == ''
```

Alternatively you could default to a boolean and optionally override. For example you might have a role that has a conditional task:

#### roles/foo/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: echo foobar
  shell: echo 'foobar'
  when: echo_foo
```

#### roles/foo/defaults/main.yml

```
echo_foo: false
```

But then we might override this at a group or hosts vars level:

#### group_vars/foobar-nodes.yml

```
echo_foo: true
```